# Compare the value of a Cell in a Column on one sheet with all the values in a column on another sheet. Color the row depending on the result

Tags: vba, excel

I have a list of names on Sheet1 ColumnA and need to see if they appear in Sheet2 ColumnB.

If a name on Sheet1 ColumnA exist on Sheet2 ColumnB, I need to color the Row on Sheet1.ColumnA Green. If not, color the row Red.

---

The code that ended up working for my specific issue was this:

```
Sub ColorCells()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim c, Finder
With Sheets("Sheet1")
    For Each c In .Range("A1:A" & .Cells(Rows.CountLarge, "A").End(xlUp).Row)
        Set Finder = Sheets("Sheet2").Range("B:B").Find(c.Value, LookAt:=xlWhole)
        If Not Finder Is Nothing Then
            c.EntireRow.Interior.Color = RGB(180, 230, 180)
        Else
            c.EntireRow.Interior.Color = RGB(230, 180, 180)
        End If
    Next c
End With
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Do you want to color the whole row or just that column?

Comment: Question is quite vague - I showed a method for exact matches - you could also do `instr` matches using `find` if you were looking for partial names within cells. Not quite clear what you want

Comment: Why not Conditional Formatting with using a ISNUMBER(MATCH()) formula?

Answer (score 1):

I came up with this, hopefully ,it is what You're looking for.

```
Dim rcnt As Long, ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet
Set ws1 = Worksheets("Sheet1")
Set ws2 = Worksheets("Sheet2")
rcnt = ws2.Range("B1", ws2.Range("B2").End(xlDown)).Rows.Count

For x = 1 To rcnt
    If ws1.Cells(x, 1) = ws2.Cells(x, 2) Then
        ws1.Cells(x, 1).EntireRow.Interior.Color = RGB(0, 255, 0)
    Else:
        ws1.Cells(x, 1).EntireRow.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
    End If
Next x
```

Comment: Close but you really need nested loops if you want to do it this way. Your method assumes they are on the same row which may not be the case. Also, nested loops will take awhile depending on data size.

Comment: @user1274820 I understand, however, the question is vague and could use a little more detail

Comment: Hey sorry for being vague. Yeah they aren't the same row. So I want to compare Sheet1 Cell A1 to every value of Sheet2 Column A's cells.

I'm going to play around with this though and see if I can figure it out unless you have a good way to compare one value to an entire dataset.

Answer (score 0):

Basic solution - this may take some time if you have incredibly large data sets.

You can change `LookAt:=xlWhole` to `LookAt:=xlPart` if you want to see if the name exists in part of the cell instead of an exact match.

```
Sub ColorCells()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim c, Finder
With Sheets("Sheet1")
    For Each c In .Range("A1:A" & .Cells(Rows.CountLarge, "A").End(xlUp).Row)
        Set Finder = Sheets("Sheet2").Range("B:B").Find(c.Value, LookAt:=xlWhole)
        If Not Finder Is Nothing Then
            c.Interior.Color = RGB(180, 230, 180)
        Else
            c.Interior.Color = RGB(230, 180, 180)
        End If
    Next c
End With
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Another way you can do this using conditional formatting

[image: ConditionalFormatting]

The formulas are:

`=COUNTIFS(Sheet2!$B$1:$B$500000,A1)=0`

`=COUNTIFS(Sheet2!$B$1:$B$500000,A1)>0`

You can change the ranges in the formula to the ranges you wish to use

You can add this to the first cell, click the Format Painter - Press F5 - and put in the range you would like it to apply to.

Finally, if your values are unique, you can use this method:

This should be a very fast method using dictionaries and variant arrays - all the comparisons are done in memory.

```
Sub ColorTheCells()
Dim s1, s2, r1(), r2(), d1, x
Set d1 = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
Set s1 = Sheets("Sheet1")
Set s2 = Sheets("Sheet2")
r1 = s1.Range("A1:A" & s1.Cells(Rows.CountLarge, "A").End(xlUp).Row).Value
r2 = s2.Range("B1:B" & s2.Cells(Rows.CountLarge, "B").End(xlUp).Row).Value
For x = LBound(r1, 1) To UBound(r1, 1)
    d1.Add r1(x, 1), x
Next x
s1.Range("A1:A" & s1.Cells(Rows.CountLarge, "A").End(xlUp).Row).Interior.Color = RGB(230, 180, 180)
For x = LBound(r2, 1) To UBound(r2, 1)
    If d1.Exists(r2(x, 1)) Then s1.Cells(d1(r2(x, 1)), s1.Cells(1, 1).Column).Interior.Color = RGB(180, 230, 180)
Next x
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks. The first example worked perfectly for what I needed.

Comment: I changed c.Interior.Color = RGB(180, 230, 180) to c.EntireRow.Interior.Color = RGB(180, 230, 180) but otherwise worked flawlessly once I adjusted the code to reflect my sheets.

Comment: You can also use `Intersect(c.EntireRow,s1.UsedRange).Interior.Color` if you don't want it to go outside of the data